# How to simulate real keyboard event with custom virtual keyboard?

Tags: javascript, keyboard

I will explain with pseudo code what i want to do in javascript. I've created custom keyboard in html/css like this

[image]

and my pseudo code what i want to do

html code

`<div class="key w-key" onclick="qwertyKeyboard('w')">w</div>`

javascript code

```
function qwertyKeyboard(char) {

  if (event.key == char ) { //event.key = 'w'
    press this event.key
  }
}
```

something like this. In general when i click any character with my mouse the clicked character should be pressed as real keyboard

Comment: why do you want to press real keyboard? What are you trying to achieve

Comment: @KaranKiri  i'm trying to create custom keyboard instead of windows's virtual keyboard

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EventTarget.dispatchEvent(Event)` to programmatically trigger an event. You would have to pass an entire `Event` object manually though. Something like `{key: "w", keycode: ...etc }`

See: [EventTarget.dispatchEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent) for more in depth info.

Answer (score 0):

you can take button for your virtual keyboard which will listen your mouse onclick event
this will send the value defined to each button

```js
function qwertyKeyboard() {
   
   var key= document.getElementById("w").value;
   alert(key)
    }
```

```html
<button  id="w" value="w" onclick="qwertyKeyboard()">w</button>
```

this is JS logic to render the click event then whatever ou want to implement after getting the value by mouse click on each of the button of the keyboard(virtual).

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your question i think you want to simulate keyboard press by clicking on your virtual keyboard

so here is a small snippet in jquery to simulate key press

```
  var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
  e.which = 112;       // code for key f1
  $(document).trigger(e);//
```

what you want to do is replace the 112 with the appropriate keycode of the pressed key